# Clearer alternative to "Here Documents"

Tags: bash, heredoc

When creating a file `example` in a bash script, you can use `cat` and a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) with `EOF` as delimiter:

```
cat <<EOF > example
1234
ABCD
EFGH
EOF
```

This looks quite complicated to a bash newbie, so would there be a clearer version to write this code?

Comment: What looks simpler?  Using `echo "multiple lines of string" > example`, with the redirection before or after the multi-line string according to whim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From man bash:

> If the redirection operator is `<<-`, then all leading TAB characters
>   are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter. This
>   allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural
>   fashion.

So this looks much cleaner:

```
cat <<-EOF > example
    1234
    ABCD
    EFGH
EOF
```

where the spaces before each line are TABs!